# Instant Remesh Blender add-on error in blender 2.91

Tags: mesh, add-on, error

I'm encountering an error when trying to use instant_mesh_remesh add-on in blender build 2.91. I followed the exact steps in https://blender-addons.org/instant-meshes-remesh/. When I try to use the use it from the object context menu, I get the following error.

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):   File    "C:\Users\Dreamscapes\AppData\Roaming\Blender    Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\aa.py", line 135, in execute    subprocess.run(cmd)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 488, in   run    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\python\lib\subprocess.py",  line 800, in __init__    restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender
2.91\2.91\python\lib\subprocess.py",    line 1207, in _execute_child    startupinfo) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
       location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: Try https://developer.blender.org/ to report bugs, you'll get a faster response.

Comment: Thanks, for now I'll just be opening in standalone version of instant meshes and hope this will be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Under this addon's settings when you first select the Instant Meshes Executable it uses a relative path. Manually set the full path to the EXE.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by using the path of the source app path by accessing the path through *Show Package Contents* then copying the path of the MACOS app.